# Fit a spatial model in spaMM, glmmTMB, or R-INLA

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme, glmmtmb, r-inla

I have a dataset that contains two sites (i.e., sites 1 and 2). The data in each site is arranged in a row-column layout (e.g., 3 rows by 4 columns). Below is an example for my dataset, where trt is the main factor of interest, and row, column, and site are blocking factors.

```
nsite <- 2
nrow <- 3
ncol <- 4
nperSite <- nrow*ncol
site <- factor(rep(1:nsite, each = nperSite))
d1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2)
d2 <- c(1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3)
trt  <- factor(c(d1,d2))
row  <- c(rep(1:nrow,each=ncol),rep(1:nrow,each=ncol))
col  <- c(rep(1:ncol,nrow),rep(1:ncol,nrow))
y    <- matrix(0,nrow=nsite*nperSite,1)
data <- data.frame(trt, row, col, site, y)
```

I would like to build a spatial model for my data, where each site has its own random error (epsilon1 for site 1 and epsilon2 for site 2). Within each site, I want to use the first-order auto-regressive model to model a spatial correlation for rows and columns (see Section 3.2.1 in https://idahoagstats.github.io/guide-to-field-trial-spatial-analysis/background.html). This means for site 1, we have a spatial correction: AR(r1) and AR(c1), and for site 2, we have a spatial correlation: AR(r2) and AR(c2). Does anyone know whether it is possible to fit such a spatial model in spaMM (https://gitlab.mbb.univ-montp2.fr/francois/spamm-ref), glmmTMB, or R-INLA?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here you might ask on the `r-sig-mixed-model@r-project.org` mailing list. I don't *think* this is available in spaMM (definitely not in glmmTMB), maybe in INLA. Does https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/612036v1 help you?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will send my question to the mailling list. Do you think whether it is possible to have such a model in glmmTMB in the near future? I will look at the paper. Thanks very much!

Comment: Please wait a little while to see if you get answers here (although I think it's unlikely), and if/when you do post on r-sig-mixed either delete these question *or* give a link to it (having the same question posted in multiple venues simultaneously can be inefficient/frustrating if people are answering in both places)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will wait for a few days before posting it on the mailling list. Yes, when I post, I will give a link to my question.